# Sending Email via Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a problem with Apps Script and sending email. I'm using a Google Form and a Google Sheet to collect data. When the survey is send, I linked the main function to a trigger so the main perform some calculation and generate a PDF. At the end of the main, a function for sending an email is called, but I have an error. I also added Gmail API. I tried to add more link into oauthScopes in my appsscript.json, but I had the same result.

This is my appsscript.json:

```
{
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify"
  ],
  "timeZone": "America/Toronto",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Gmail",
        "version": "v1",
        "serviceId": "gmail"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

This is my function that's called by my main:

```
function sendEmail(email, pdfFile){
  var subject = "Test";
  var message = "Hi";

  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
}
```

When this function is call, I have the following problem:

```
Exception: The script does not have permission to perform that action. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify || https://mail.google.com/ || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose)
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you run the function manually (from the IDE), in order to authorize the scopes needed?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function sendEmail(email, pdfFile){
  var subject = "Test";
  var message = "Hi";
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {attachments:[pdfFile]});
}
```

Comment: I have the same result: The script does not have permission to perform that action.